# Is this possible to Drag and drop a "ReorderableGridView" item between two pages of "CarouselSlider.builder" in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to drag and drop an item from the "ReorderableGridView between two pages of "CarouselSlider.builder". "CarouselSlider.builder" has two pages and each page has a "ReorderableGridView" as its "itemBuilder". Drag and drop is working fine within the same "ReorderableGridView", but It won't work for the other page.

I need to drag an item from one page of "CarouselSlider.builder" and drop it to the other page of "CarouselSlider.builder".

Please let me know how to achieve this. Do I need to replace the "ReorderableGridView" with some other tool? Or Do I need to replace the "CarouselSlider.builder" with "ListView"?